# Only show element after C# method has successfully run

Tags: c#, html, .net, webforms

I am making a contact page in ASP.NET framework and I am trying to make a box apear after I have sent an email, but I dont know how to show the message ONLY when the method has run, I can make it disapear after a short amount of time but everytime I refresh the page the box comes back. Heres what ive come up with:

My submit button and Label1 is what I want to show only when my Clickfunction has ran:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" placeholder="Namn"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Fyll i Namn" ControlToValidate="txtName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" placeholder="E-mail"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Fyll i Email" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Felaktig Email" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <input style="display: none" type="text" name="phone" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" placeholder="Telefon" AutoCompleteType="HomePhone"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Fyll i Telefon" ControlToValidate="txtPhone"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" placeholder="Meddelande" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="8"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Fyll i Meddelande" ControlToValidate="txtMessage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Skicka" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="disableElement()" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
        <br />
        <div id="labelBox">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Tack för ditt meddelande!"></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

My click function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Clicked");
            try
            {
                if (Page.IsValid)
                {
                    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]);
                    mailMessage.To.Add(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]);
                    mailMessage.Subject = "Förfrågan";
                    mailMessage.Body = "Namn: " + txtName.Text + "<br />" + "Telefon: " + txtPhone.Text + "<br />" + txtMessage.Text;
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]);

                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                    txtName.Text = String.Empty;
                    txtEmail.Text = String.Empty;
                    txtPhone.Text = String.Empty;
                    txtMessage.Text = String.Empty;
                    

                }
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Problem" + ex;
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you're probably looking for the "Visible" property.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="False" Text="Tack för ditt meddelande!"></asp:Label>
```

Then when you want to make it visible client-side just do

```
Label1.Visible = true;
```

inside your event handler.

The "Visible" property prevents the control from being pushed to the client PC at all. If you want the control to exist client-side, but be hidden, the easiest method might be to define a CSS class

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

and then use the CssClass property

```
Label1.CssClass = "";
```

or

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" Text="Tack för ditt meddelande!"></asp:Label>
```

to show/hide the controls.

Comment: It now displays when  I send the mail, but is there a way that I can make it disapear after like 5 seconds, and after it disapears if I refresh it doesnt show up again?

Comment: Add a class with css transition-delay set.

Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635784/show-hide-elements-with-animation/55636032
W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Regarding refreshing the page, if needed, you can reset object state in the page_load event. Just add Label1.Visible = false.

Comment: Good to hear. : )