# How to use prev/next for a group of div elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So im trynna make a whole group of elements go next and frouth , off a code I took here but I edited it

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<div class="divs">
    <div class="cls1">
        <div>Yes 1 </div>
        <div>Element 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cls2">
        <div>Yes 1 </div>
        <div>Element 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cls3">
        <div>Yes 1 </div>
        <div>Element 1 </div>
    </div>

</div>
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

When I click next , nothing shows up.And when I spam it random elements show up separately, I was the both elements to show up when I click next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you didn't use classes, use something like ".divs>div" to pinpoint the element if not the children would be included on the selection.
2. It's just my preferences but if you code, one line is okay if the meaning is clear, but for this one it seems wasteful and not clear in a glance. It's also better to assign to variable than searching multiple times.

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<div class="divs">
    <div class="item cls1">
        <div>Yes 1 </div>
        <div>Element 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item cls2">
        <div>Yes 2 </div>
        <div>Element 2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item cls3">
        <div>Yes 3 </div>
        <div>Element 3 </div>
    </div>

</div>
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs>div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
          $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $("#next").click(function(){
      const visibleDiv = $(".divs>div:visible");
      const nextDiv = visibleDiv.next();
      if(nextDiv.length > 0) {
        visibleDiv.hide();
        nextDiv.show();
      }

    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
      const visibleDiv = $(".divs>div:visible");
      const prevDiv = visibleDiv.prev();
      if(prevDiv.length > 0) {
        visibleDiv.hide();
        prevDiv.show();
      }
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Also is there any way to add animations?

Comment: it's my pleasure. For animation you can check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635784/show-hide-elements-with-animation. I think the example already really good there.